# Sentence Structure habit / question

Tags: questions, syntactic-analysis

I frequently find my writing style to be less than optimal when it comes to the structure of my sentences. For example, when I ask questions most of my sentences resemble the following: 
 `Are we able to access the demo also?`

Should this sentence rather be written as: `Are we also able to access the demo?`

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside: Is "struct" a word? Structure, surely?

Anyway, your intuition is correct. Most English speakers would instinctively say the latter sounds better, though they might not know the reason.

In general, it is a good idea to have the adverb adjacent to the verb it is modifying. In this case "also" is the adverb and "able" is the verb so having them next to each other is clearer.